# PrimeNG Table Angular 6. Connect Column Toggle and Selection

Tags: angular6, primeng

How can I connect column Toggle and Selection Checkbox from PrimeNG Table.
Link to PrimeNG table: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

I have table like this and these two things can't work properly together:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vhtx.png)

Comment: seems like you have not used the primeng grid system properly. Please follow the link and use the appropriate class. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/grid. In most case you need to override the css styles

Answer (score 0):

The issue may due to the [(ngModel)] please import formsmodule in your app module to use the ngmodel.

If the issue still persist then show us the code.